# to check an coredata object is nil

Tags: ios, core-data, nspredicate

I want to find out the objects in the core data, my code:

Types:

`signedDate` (Date)

`alarmDate`(Date)

`starTime`(NSDate)

`endTime`(NSDate)

```
NSString *str = @"(signedDate >= %@) AND (signedDate < %@) AND (alarmDate == nil)";
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:str, starTime, endTime];
[request setPredicate:predicate];
NSArray *results=[context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

predicate is wrong ?
How to judge an coredata object is nil? 
What the predicate should be?

Comment: Please add a closing " to the str assignment to fix the color formatting.  I can't because that edit is less than 6 characters.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I don't think the predicate syntax calls for == nil.
Use only one =

```
NSString *str = @"(signedDate >= %@) AND (signedDate < %@) AND (alarmDate = nil)";
```

Your code above works right. It should be YES since it's nil.

```
BOOL ok;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = nil"];
ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:
[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"firstName"]];
```

Comment: = and == is equivalent in predicate syntax. [Here is the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pSyntax.html).

Comment: =, == The left-hand expression is equal to the right-hand expression.

Answer (score 10):

From [apple docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Predicates/Articles/pUsing.html)

**Testing for Null**

If you want to match null values, you must include a specific test in addition to other comparisons, as illustrated in the following fragment.

```
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(firstName == %@) || (firstName = nil)", firstName];
filteredArray = [array filteredArrayUsingPredicate:predicate];
NSLog(@"filteredArray: %@", filteredArray);

// Output:
// filteredArray: ( { lastName = Turner; }, { birthday = 1972-03-23 20:45:32 -0800; firstName = Ben; lastName = Ballard; }
```

By implication, a test for null that matches a null value returns true. In the following code fragment, ok is set to YES for both predicate evaluations.

```
BOOL ok;
predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName = nil"];
ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

ok = [predicate evaluateWithObject:
    [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSNull null] forKey:@"firstName"]];
```

Comment: I don't understand, how to edit my code? alarmDate is an attribute in an entity of coredata

Comment: I just want to find out the objects that its signedDate is between startTime and endTime, and also alarmDate is nil

Comment: yes but how do you know it isn't working, is it throwing an error or returning the wrong results?