# coredata fetch records where the relation is not existing

Tags: swift, core-data

I have an entity in swift with an optional relation towards another entity. Now I want to select those records without a relation towards the other entity.

I tried with a predicate (format: "relation = %@", nill) but this does not work.

how to fetch records without the relation filled?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [to check an coredata object is nil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10245958/to-check-an-coredata-object-is-nil)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest = YourEntity.fetchRequest()
let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "%K == nil", #keyPath(YourEntity.yourOptionalAttribute))
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate
// the rest of your code to perform the fetch goes here
```

`@K` is for `keyPath`. You just want to search where the keyPath is `nil`.